# Динамическая память в С++

Tags: c++

```
Beverage * beverage2 = new DarkRoast();
beverage2 = new Whip(*beverage2);

delete beverage2;
```

Имеется абстрактный класс Beverage и его наследники: DarkRoast и Whip.
При таком коде будет ли утечка памятью? И если да, то как правильнее переписать этот код так, чтобы не создавать лишнюю переменную, если вообще это реально. На java так получается довольно-таки легко.

Comment: Неизвестно, будет или нет. Может у вас в Whip delete будет выполняться.

Comment: Во многих случая можно без new обойтись, объявляя локальные переменные, тогда никакого delete вам не понадобится.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Неизвестно.

Если есть конструктор `Whip`, принимающий ссылку, то утечки **может** не быть.

```
Whip(Beverage &p) : p(p) {};
```

В остальных случаях утечка есть, поскольку старое значение указателя `beverage2` теряется.

Например, я могу дописать код так, что утечки не будет: https://ideone.com/lhxozT

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Beverage
{
  static int last;
  int i;
  Beverage() : i(++last) {}
  virtual ~Beverage() { cout << "~Beverage #" << i << endl;  }
};

int Beverage::last = 0;

struct DarkRoast : Beverage
{
  virtual ~DarkRoast() { cout << "~DarkRoast #" << i << endl; }
};

struct Whip : Beverage
{
  Beverage &p;
  Whip(Beverage &p) : p(p) {};
  virtual ~Whip() { cout << "~Whip #" << i << endl; delete &p; }
};

int main()
{
  Beverage * beverage2 = new DarkRoast();
  beverage2 = new Whip(*beverage2);
  delete beverage2;

  return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
~Whip #2
~DarkRoast #1
~Beverage #1
~Beverage #2
```

Comment: Человек явно только начинает постигать C++, а вы ему такие вещи предлагаете. Конструктор который по ссылке принимает объект, а потом захватывает права на владения им.

Comment: @ffk, вопрос был "есть ли утечка памяти". Она может быть, а может не быть. Я привёл пример, в котором её нет, в остальных она есть. Чем именно тебя не устраивает этот ответ?

Comment: @Abyx, зато [в комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/733134/%d0%94%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%a1/733150?noredirect=1#comment1114389_733136) сказано.

Comment: @Abyx, кстати, невирутуальный деструктор приведёт к UB ведь и утечки там будут меньшей проблемой?

Comment: @Qwertiy Тем что человек не разбирается с C++, а бравировать выкрутасами C++ за которые в продакшен коде отрываю ноги, не надо. Это как первокласснику объяснять что можно извлекать квадратные корни из отрицательных чисел, не объясня область применимости данной теории.

Comment: @ffk а за что руки то отрвут? Вполне нормальный код.

Comment: @pavel, передача владения объектом через ссылку вместо указателя.

Answer (score 3):

Будет. Потому что вы присваиваете новое значение, теряя старое - и больше не сможете ни обратиться к объекту класса `DarkRoast`, ни освободить занятую им память.

Здесь не Java, сборки мусора, к счастью, нет :)

И еще - очень надеюсь, что вы знаете, что если удаляете наследника через указатель на предка - то деструктор должен быть виртуальным?...

Comment: При `new Whip(Beverage &smth)` утечки может и не быть, если тот дестуктор удалит его.

Comment: Про деструктор знаю само-собой.

Comment: @Qwertiy В смысле, конструктор? Но мы же рассматривает общий случай.

Comment: @Harry, загляни в мой ответ. Заодно проверь, не накосячил ли я где.

Comment: Кстати, @Harry, а какой общий случай? Я вижу передачу разыменованного указателя в конструктор - зачем-то же она нужна.

Comment: @Qwertiy Обычное копирование.